# Is a dropdown design or a picker view design better ui design?

Tags: ios

[image]

In this picture I have created 3 buttons styled like dropdown menus. When i click those buttons it shows the choices in dropdown format. However, in some articles I have read dropdown designs are uncomfortable for users.

Would it be better to use 3 textboxes that trigger [iOS PickerViews](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-7-using-the-uipickerview/) or should I keep the dropdown menus?

Comment: This question is not readable, even with the picture I can't figure out what you mean. Is the question: is it better to have a date/time picker than several dropdown menus to select a date/time? Please, try and rephrase the question :-)

Comment: yeah @xabre ..i rephrase it...

Comment: must be hard for non native speakers to pitch questions, lets try and help him out

Comment: what's wrong with my question? i am new to ios development i just asked dropdown or picker view which one is good? in some articles, i read picker views are good one....dropdown designs are uncomfort for users..that's why i posted this question

Comment: @boopathis I appreciate the effort at clarifying but I don't think it helped, I think it is a loss in translation to where I can't see the differences between your two choices. If this is an interface for selecting the date I suggest using the word date in the question. I think the main problem is I don't see what this interface is supposed to do.

Comment: @boopathis after reading up on what "pickerviews" are I took the liberty of clarifying the question to try and eliminate translation errors. If I assumed anything wrongly please clarify or rollback the edits.

Comment: The images you've added do not make sense with the questions you've asked. A little more detail and better formatting might go a long way.

Comment: There is also a Date Picker Control in iOS, so no need for 3 individual Pickers. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html

Comment: At this moment, it is, to me, still unclear if this is for picking a date, or anything else. As usual, these things depend on a few things. In general, I'd say, use the datepicker for dates, use the regular picker for a long list of options that you want to show to a user, probably because it that is the primary use-case, it prevents a click at the cost of space. A dropdown would be favored in case the component should be accesible, but not as a primary use case. If the list of options is limited (e.g. 4 items), consider using a radiobutton instead.

Comment: http://imgur.com/1ztRQja

http://imgur.com/aHycj2k

http://imgur.com/XIR4ero   yeah these are my dropdown screen shots when i click those 3 buttons  it shows a dropdown format and if i select values it shown in their respective labels...  then  second is a picker view.. screen shot  http://imgur.com/nWeGIJt    i am asking which one is best....if i create 3 picker views like tis is it good...to be use?

Comment: Allright, after doing a little bit of research, there is, apparantly, no native dropdown in iOS SDK, you can make it yourself, but I doubt that that would be OK, as user have a certain expectation of interaction. With that knowledge in mind, I would stick with the pickers for iOS. *You may correct me if I'm wrong :p* - this might also help http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61345/is-there-a-design-pattern-for-dropdown-lists-in-ios

Comment: @Xabre yeah bro but if i put three picker views in single screen is it looks good....i am just asking...

Comment: If I were you, I'd test out several versions with some test-subjects (also called an A/B test). There is a lot to say about mobile dev, but making sure that items are easily *clickable* and *discoverable* are generally spoken "good practices" :-)  That way you can validate what works best for your **users**. Unless the question is *really* just about aesthetics, in which case you'll probably get a lot of opinions, but backing it up with some solid user research will get you a long way :-) Perhaps adding the use-case could help :-).

Comment: Either your question is too broad (as there is no "one is better" answer), or it's a site review question.  Unfortunately, both of those are off topic.  If you have a general question about which option is better in a given situation, you will get more useful responses on this site.